# bprof user manual

Tags: profiler

Can anyone tell me where can i get user manual for bprof?

Comment: That's a tough one, martin. Google turns up a site that brags about it, but there's no information. There is a schemey site called "Bigloo", which has "bglprof", which is a packaged "gprof", but I don't blame you for not wanting *that*.

Comment: ya, i know it is a quite old thing. thank u so much and i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

bprof? Are you referring to gprof? If so then you can get the manual [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/).